# Python split string retaining the bracket

Tags: python, string, split

I would like to split the string and eliminate the whitespaces such as

```
double a[3] = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0};
```

The expected output is

```
['double', 'a', '[', '3', ']', '=', '{', '0.0', ',', '0.0', ',', '0.0', '}', ';']
```

How could I do that with re module in Python?

Comment: That first snippet should actually be a string, `"double a[3] = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0};"`? Are you trying to build a tokenizer for some other language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of the fact that `re.split()` retains delimiters in capture groups in the output:

```
import re
input_string = "double a[3] = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0};"
bits = [bit for bit in (bit.strip() for bit in re.split(r'((?:\d+\.\d+)|[,}=;]|\w+)', input_string)) if bit]
expected = ['double', 'a', '[', '3', ']', '=', '{', '0.0', ',', '0.0', ',', '0.0', '}', ';']
assert bits == expected
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach here might be to use `re.findall`:

```py
inp = "double a[3] = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0};"
parts = re.findall(r'\d+(?:\.\d+)?|\w+|[^\s\w]', inp)
print(parts)

# ['double', 'a', '[', '3', ']', '=', '{', '0.0', ',', '0.0', ',', '0.0', '}', ';']
```

The regex pattern used here says to match:

- `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` an integer or float
- `|` OR
- `\w+` a word (such as "double")
- `|` OR
- `[^\s\w]` a single non word non whitespace (such as `{`)

Answer (score 0):

Solution without `re`:

```py
from itertools import groupby

s = "double a[3] = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0};"
delimiters = r"[]{};,"

out = []
for word in s.split():
    for k, g in groupby(word, lambda v: any(d in v for d in delimiters)):
        if k:
            out.extend(list(g))
        else:
            out.append("".join(g))

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
['double', 'a', '[', '3', ']', '=', '{', '0.0', ',', '0.0', ',', '0.0', '}', ';']
```